# Why can't I download a font asset in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I would like to do the following in rails in my `application.css`:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600,700);
```

Can someone please tell me why this won't work, or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing it like this.

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600,700"
```